# JQuery Plugin Stylesheet

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a jquery plugin which comes with its own stylesheet.  However, when I include my own stylesheet along with that of the plugin, the plugin stylesheet always gets affected by the css in my own stylesheet.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Can you provide some code? What do you mean that plugin comes with a stylesheet? Does it use inline styles?

Comment: Include your stylesheet first?  Or make sure you're not overdeclaring/creating conflicts.  Maybe you can provide your css?

Comment: it creates conflicts.  Say, the links in my style sheetsheet are red, and those in the plugin stylesheet are not declare, it is inheriting the colors.  How do i prevent that inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no quick fix. You either have to resolve conflicting styles by hand, or prefix every style in plugin's CSS with some class name, e.g.

```
.plugin-x h1 { ... }
.plugin-x li { ... }
.plugin-x .info { ... }
```

And then wrap HTML element your plugin generates in a div with that special class name:

```
  <div class="plugin-x"><!-- html generated by the plugin here --></div>
```

In the case when your own global styles affect the plugin styling, e.g. links become red, you'll have to add this style:

```
.plugin-x a { color: black }
```

Or simply edit plugin's stylesheet and specify the color you want.

Comment: Yep, like poster said, there's really no easy fix.